# Algorithm to implement a SQL-like group-by with aggregation functions over a collection?

Tags: php, javascript, python, algorithm, collections

Let's say you have an array like this:

```
[
  {'id' : 1, 'closed' : 1 },
  {'id' : 2, 'closed' : 1 },
  {'id' : 5, 'closed' : 1 },
  {'id' : 7, 'closed' : 0 },
  {'id' : 8, 'closed' : 0 },
  {'id' : 9, 'closed' : 1 }
]
```

I'd like to summarize this dataset (not using SQL!), and grabbing the `min` and `max` id for each group defined by the variation of the row `'closed'`. Resulting in output like this:

```
[
  {'id__min' : 1, 'id__max' : 5, 'closed' : 1},
  {'id__min' : 7, 'id__max' : 8, 'closed' : 0},
  {'id__min' : 9, 'id__max' : 9, 'closed' : 1}
]
```

**This is just an example of what I'd like to do.** I want to implement something that is similar to what python's `itertools.groupby` provides, but being a little more comprehensive. (Would like to define my own aggregation functions).

I am looking for pointers, pseudocode and even any of PHP, Python or Javascript code if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `key` argument to [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) allows you to pass your own aggregation function.

Comment: I know, i am looking for a generic way to implement this in another language (PHP right now).

Comment: The documentation gives the equivalent of the function in lower-level code. Feel free to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby code:

```
def summarise array_of_hashes
    #first sort the list by id
    arr = array_of_hashes.sort {|a, b| a['id'] <=> b['id'] }
    #create a hash with id_min and id_max set to the id of the first
    #array element and closed to the closed of the first array element
    hash = {}
    hash['id_min'] = hash['id_max'] = arr[0]['id']
    hash['closed'] = arr[0]['closed']
    #prepare an output array
    output = []
    #iterate over the array elements
    arr.each do |el|
        if el['closed'] == hash['closed']
            #update id_max while the id value is the same
            hash['id_max'] = el['id']
        else #once it is different
            output.push hash #add the hash to the output array
            hash = {} #create a new hash in place of the old one
            #and initiate its keys to the appropriate values
            hash['id_min'] = hash['id_max'] = el['id']
            hash['closed'] = el['closed']
        end
    end
    output.push hash #make sure the final hash is added to the output array
    #return the output array
    output
end
```

The generalised version:

```
def summarise data, condition, group_func
    #store the first hash in a variable to compare t
    pivot = data[0]
    to_group = []
    output = []
    #iterate through array
    data.each do |datum|
        #if the comparison of this datum to the pivot datum fits the condition
        if condition.call(pivot, datum)
            #add this datum to the to_group list
            to_group.push datum
        else #once the condition no longer matches
            #apply the aggregating function to the list to group and add it to the output array
            output.push group_func.call(to_group)
            #reset the to_group list and add this element to it
            to_group = [datum]
            #set the pivot to this element
            pivot = datum
        end
    end
    #make sure the final list to group are grouped and added to the output list
    output.push group_func.call(to_group)
    #return the output list
    output
end
```

The following code will then work for your example:

```
my_condition = lambda do |a, b|
    b['closed'] == a['closed']
end

my_group_func = lambda do |to_group|
    {
        'id_min' => to_group[0]['id'],
        'id_max' => to_group[to_group.length-1]['id'],
        'closed' => to_group[0]['closed']
    }
end

summarise(my_array.sort {|a, b| a['id'] <=> b['id']}, my_condition, my_group_func)
```

The generalised algorithm will work in any language that allows passing functions as arguments to other functions. It will also work with an array of variables of any data type if the correct condition and aggregating functions are used.

Comment: This works, although what I need is to generalize the approach. That means being able to pass my own aggregation functions or defining the condition that creates new groupings in a standard way.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a generalised version. I hope the code + comments are sufficient to allow porting to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP version of the Ruby code with slightly more generic naming and id order handling:

```
$input = array(
    array('id' => 3, 'closed' => 1),
    array('id' => 2, 'closed' => 1),
    array('id' => 5, 'closed' => 1),
    array('id' => 7, 'closed' => 0),
    array('id' => 8, 'closed' => 0),
    array('id' => 9, 'closed' => 1)
);

$output = min_max_group($input, 'id', 'closed');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($output); echo '</pre>';

function min_max_group($array, $name, $group_by)
{
    $output = array();

    $tmp[$name.'__max'] = $tmp[$name.'__min'] =  $array[0][$name];
    $tmp[$group_by] = $array[0][$group_by];

    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        if($value[$group_by] == $tmp[$group_by])
        {
            if($value[$name] < $tmp[$name.'__min']) { $tmp[$name.'__min'] = $value[$name]; }
            if($value[$name] > $tmp[$name.'__max']) { $tmp[$name.'__max'] = $value[$name]; }
        }
        else
        {
            $output[] = $tmp;

            $tmp[$name.'__max'] = $tmp[$name.'__min'] = $value[$name];
            $tmp[$group_by] = $value[$group_by];

            if($value[$name] < $tmp[$name.'__min']) { $tmp[$name.'__min'] = $value[$name]; }
            if($value[$name] > $tmp[$name.'__max']) { $tmp[$name.'__max'] = $value[$name]; }
        }
    }

    $output[] = $tmp;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this stuff with specific data, I am looking for ways to generalize it.

Comment: That function takes in any array and extracts 1 column you specify grouped by another that you specify returning a general array using the names you specified. I think I'm missing exactly what else it is you would like to generalise? I can only assume you wish to define grouping functions etc?

Comment: Exactly, I want a generic way to implement callbacks that I can pass to the function for extracting the `min` or `max` or whatever I wish on a group's values. Also, a way to define a comparison function for determining a new group(maybe specifying more than one field, etc). :-)

Comment: User defined callbacks are easy in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php . You could then just pass in function names / parameters etc and have other functions handle the grouping tests etc. In my own opinion though once you have defined several of these you might as well have just called the other functions directly rather than shoving them through the above (which is basically just an array loop)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but isn't this just a standard [map/reduce](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/03/14/map-reduce-ndash-a-visual-explanation.aspx) problem?

Comment: You might as well say, "Why not just use data processing?"